# Responsive video CSS

Tags: css, html, video

I'm trying to create a responsive video background that sits below my header (so not entirely fullscreen)

My problem is that I can't manage to figure out the CSS required to have it fill the space, maintain resolution, and resize (without creating gaps) on smaller screens.

Here is a link of the exact effect I'm looking for.
http://www.matthewemvintaylor.co.uk/

Please note I do not want to use Video.JS or BigVid.JS as I'm doing lots of ajax stuff with the video source and don't want to have to figure out how to make them all work together.

Here is my html

```
<header>
    <div class="navigation">
        title
    </div>
</header>

<div class="content">
    <div class="video-wrapper">
        <video id="video-element" autoplay loop>
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
.navigation {
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the width and the height of the video with a percentage value.
In this case the video is 100% width and height of is container

```
#video-element{
position: absolute;
object-fit: cover;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

You can use
`object-fit:cover`
to increases or decreases the size of the video to fill the box whilst preserving its aspect-ratio.
 [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gioele/q3tow97g/)

Comment: Unfortunately this leaves a massive white space below if I make the browser narrow enough

Comment: This works for me [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gioele/q3tow97g/) EDIT: just noticed that i gave you the wrong value for object-fit. it is not contain, it is cover

Comment: And a few more attributes like position, top, and left and it worked! Thanks!