# Responsive video default size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, youtube, responsive

I have a website using bootstrap and on the core of my page I have a picture and below is a youtube video embeded:

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">

      <a href="tech.php">
        <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="assets/tech_withText.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="1200" height="600">
      </a>

      <br>

      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RTwv1Dn2rYQ" width="300" height="150" frameborder="0" autoplay=1 allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>

    </div>
```

[Link to website here.](http://www.lescompanions.com)

When I first load this page what I see with this solution (and dislike) is that my video extends below my screen. So I am after a way to state the size of my picture and video as a ratio of the screen size, so that my video resizes to stay within the boundaries of the screen.

I have looked for ideas on the internet (i.e. css edit [as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908324/responsive-video-css)) but I get lost or it does not do what I expect.

Any idea?

Comment: If you want to use only css and keep your header image and embedded video inside the fold, you could assign the .container class a small width on large resolutions. If you replace the 1170px with 970px  both the elements would remain visibile inside the fold of the maximized browser window.

Answer (score 1):

If you just add a CSS entry to specify the minimum height of the video it will not clip it on load and bootstrap will take care of keeping it in ratio on resize. Code:

```
.embed-responsive{
  min-height:100%;
}
```

Of course you will probably want to target the div a little more specifically but I think this should do what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

I would go about this differently, I wouldn't use an absolute positioned element for video and I would set a `height` or `min-height` to use viewport units `vh`

So it might look like:

```
#youtube-video {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 40vh;
}
```

And remove all the absolute positioning on that element.

Additionally you might want to set an ID or class on your top container and give it some `margin-top` to offset your fixed header:

```
#top-container {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Lastly I would move the `footer` outside the bootstrap container completely by moving the `</div>` to be above your `footer`.

```
<div class="container">
....
</div>
<footer class="footer">
...
</footer>
```